# Do we need Mass Effect have tags for each installment, or should those tags be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed we have tags [mass-effect](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect), [mass-effect-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-2), and [mass-effect-3](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-3). Do we really need a tag for each installment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No, we don't.**

---

We have [37 questions tagged](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-3+or+mass-effect-2+or+mass-effect) with any of those tags. Of those 37, we have

- [26 questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect+-mass-effect-3+-mass-effect-2) tagged with just [mass-effect](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect)
- [1 question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-2+-mass-effect-3+-mass-effect) tagged with just [mass-effect-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-2)
- [4 questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-3+-mass-effect+-mass-effect-2) tagged with just [mass-effect-3](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-3)

The tag wiki excerpt for [mass-effect-3](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-3) already says that it should always be used in conjunction with [mass-effect](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect).

This leads me to the conclusion that these tags add very little over the general tag.

---

**[mass-effect-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-2) and [mass-effect-3](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-3) should be synonyms for [mass-effect](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect).**

Comment: Done. Padding chars!

Comment: @Keen Great work!

Answer (score 1):

They should be separate tags. They're each for different works that will each have their own questions. The misuse of [mass-effect](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect) as a franchise tag should end though, as that confuses the first game with the franchise.  I propose a [mass-effect-franchise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-franchise) for this purpose.

Synonymizing them into one would be like merging all the individual *Star Wars* film tags into one. It destroys the correctly fine-grained nature of the tags.

Comment: Should we create a separate 'mass-effect-series' or similar tag?

Comment: @phantom42 I was thinking [tag:mass-effect-franchise] ala [tag:alien-franchise].

Comment: Star Wars only needs separate tags for each film because the volume of questions justifies it, otherwise tagging with the franchise and allowing the context of the question to determine which installment is in question is sufficient.  Lets put it this way - would a tag for each episode of firefly be justified?

Comment: @Tritium21 Is each episode of Firefly a dozen+ hours long?

Comment: That does not really matter.  Its not about the quality of the product or the number of installments, its about volume of questions and the likelihood of experts to be able to answer questions of the tag.  A Mass Effect expert is likely to be able to answer a question from the entire series AND the volume of questions does not justify multiple tags.